# Create a new array by getting the first value of each array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays like this

```
[
 [2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
]
```

And I am trying to create a new array by getting the `first` value of each array so the output will be

```
[
 [2, 4, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1],
 [2, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0]
]
```

Is there any workarounds to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: A loop should do the job. So... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I thought it would be more complexed than a loop, thanks for the help anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping based on the subarray length, using `Array.prototype.flatMap`, you can get the array of the `i`th item of child array as a new array.

```js
const input = [
  [2, 0, 0, 2, 0],
  [4, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
];

const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input[0].length; i ++) {
  output.push(input.flatMap(item => item[i]));
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will accept answer once I am not in cooldown

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw is it just a typo that your input is `4*5` matrix and the output is `4*4` matrix?

Comment: @AlanOmar It's a typo, I fixed it, thanks.